# Put together template specializations

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Say I have following code

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N>
int calcFac() {

    return N*calcFac<N-1>();
}

template<>
int calcFac<1> () {

    return 1;   
}

template<>
int calcFac<0> () {

    return 1;   
}

int main() {

    int f4 = calcFac<4>();
    int f5 = calcFac<5>();
    int f1 = calcFac<1>();
    int f0 = calcFac<0>();

    std::cout <<"4! = "<<f4<<std::endl;
    std::cout <<"5! = "<<f5<<std::endl;
    std::cout <<"1! = "<<f1<<std::endl;
    std::cout <<"0! = "<<f0<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a possibility (i.e. does the STL offer a construct) to lump together the two specialized cases `calcFac<0>` and `calcFac<1>`, so that I need only one function for both cases?

I.e.: `calcFac</*if this parameter is 0 or 1 use that template function*/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:
My original design is flawed (doesn't work correctly with `calcFac<0>()`). I take the design from @xaxxon instead. Saving my original design needs declaring three functions, but it does lump together the two specialised cases. You can find it at the very end of this answer.

There is, by using SFINAE and `std::enable_if_t`

```
#include <type_traits>
template <int N>
std::enable_if_t<N <= 1, int> calcFac() {
  return 1;
}

template<int N>
std::enable_if_t<!(N <= 1), int> calcFac() {
  return N*calcFac<N-1>();
}
```

How does this work:

`std::enable_if_t<exp, Type>` is equivalent to `Type` if `exp` is `true`, and undeclared otherwise. By using `std::enable_if_t` this way in return type, will cause a [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) error when `exp` is `false`, thus the function is out of candidate list.

---

```
#include <type_traits>
template <int N>
std::enable_if_t<N<=1, int> calcFacImpl(int) {
  return 1;
}

template <int N>
int calcFacImpl(...) {
  return N*calcFacImpl<N-1>(0);
}

template <int N>
int calcFac() {
  return calcFacImpl<N>(0);
}
```

Comment: it's weird to introduce an unused parameter like that, though.   Something like this: https://godbolt.org/g/epF0wQ  seems more straightforward to me.  Though I'd probably do this with structs not functions in the first place.  Something more like: https://godbolt.org/g/PB0Agq

Comment: I am not sure if "SFINAE error" is the correct term. If you spell it out it sounds a bit weird: substitution failure is not an error error ...

Comment: @xaxxon it's true, using a parameter does make things more complicated. But the original question asks how to lump together the two specialised cases...

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, sounds weird... But cppreference has used it that way(you can find it in the link), and as a non native English speaker, I just followed it blindly...

Comment: @felix: Yep, I could have thrown away the <1> case in the first place without changing the behavior of the code in any way. I just put that case in to learn how to extent a specialized template function to cover two special cases

Comment: Would the correct term be 'substitution failure' then?

Comment: @felix actually I also wouldnt know how to call it. On cppref they use it to make the difference between a "SFINAE error" and "hard error". As I understand SFINAE it is not an error and should not be called so. I hope the right term is just "substitution failure" (because thats what it really is and not an error ;), but I cannot find a good proof for that.

Comment: ps: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) writes: "[...] results in a deduction failure [..], but the program is well-formed". To my understanding, if it is well-formed it cannot be an error. However, I am not an expert to decide, it might well be that "SFINAE error" is commonly used

Answer (score 0):

In soon-to-be-standardized C++1z, you can use `if constexpr`

```
template<int N>
auto calcFac() {
    if constexpr (N > 1)  {
        return N * calcFac<N-1>();
    }
    return 1;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mzprc41mqMyGALsm)